# detect first page load jquery session

Tags: asp.net, jquery, session

Once the user logs in, i am displaying an alert to user based on a check on page load method. Now when the user navigates to other aspx pages and clicks on home again, I don’t want him to see the alert again. I want to achieve this with jquery and session variable. In a way I want to check first page load by jquery using a session variable.

Comment: Hook a `jQuery.ajax` or `jQuery.getJSON` call up to a server-side page that returns your session variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this exact feature a couple of weeks ago, but used a mySQL database instead of using sessions. If you are wanting to display the alert to the user only once EVER (or as close to forever as possible) or just once a week etc, then you should use cookies instead of sessions.

Otherwise, you can detect when the page has loaded simply with jQuery:

```
$().ready(function(){
    if(!$.session.get("viewed_page")){
        alert("some message"); 
        $.session.set("viewed_page", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, yes I should have included that you will need the session plugin! https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin

Comment: thanks JackalopeZero, but not allowed to add the plugin...is there a jquery inbuilt way of doing it

Comment: Sure, see setting and checking cookies: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: I think it uses `sessionStorage` HTML5 feature. I dont think it will be supported by `IE7`

Comment: yea Murali, thats correct...i dont think there is a easy cheesy way to do it from jquery without using HTML 5

Comment: @hercules, check the option 2 in my answer :)

Comment: for the people who are using HTML 5 features, i am marking this as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I could do this with Session and [`RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx)

User Login code

```
public void doLogin(string userName, string pwd)
{
 // validate user 
 // check to see whether need to show alert
  Session["ShowAlert"]=true;
  Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
}
```

in Home.aspx

**Option 1**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if(Session["ShowAlert"]!=null)
{
    String scriptName = "PopupScript";


    if (!IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(csname1))
    {
      StringBuilder cstext = new StringBuilder();
      cstext.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> function showUserAlert() {");
      cstext.Append("alert('message');} ");
      cstext.Append("</script>");
      RegisterStartupScript(cstext, cstext.ToString());

      Session.Remove("ShowAlert");
    }

}
}
```

**Option 2:**

Just define a javascript variable `var` in the page and use it in `$(function(){...})`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if(Session["ShowAlert"]!=null)
{
    String scriptName = "PopupScript";


    if (!IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(csname1))
    {
      StringBuilder cstext = new StringBuilder();
      cstext.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
      cstext.Append("var showAlert=true;");
      cstext.Append("</script>");
      RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstext, cstext.ToString());

      Session.Remove("ShowAlert");
    }

}
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(showAlert)
{
 alert('ShowMessage');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for session here.

You can use the session cookie itself.

```
$(function (){
  if (document.cookie.indexOf("yourToken")>-1)
  {}
  else
  {
  // show the window , and set a cookie
  }
});
```